# Absolute labels for notes -- collaborative tex writing git

Tags: cross-referencing, notes, git

The context is collaborative latex writing using GIT and some online repository. I have a simple macro that uses a counter to index notes in a pdf, which puts a number in the margin:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcounter{mynote}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{% a simple margin note
        \refstepcounter{mynote}% step counter
        {\color{red} ToNote;~#1
        \marginnote{\color{red}\mbox{\textbf{[\themynote]}}}}% the note
}
  
\begin{document}
Here is some text \note{with a note.}

\end{document}
```

The problem with this solution is that the labels will change (in general) each time a new note is added in the text. This makes it hard to discuss when several versions are pushed/merged, with text edits and new notes added.

I have no MWE for this as I am not sure how I should proceed: would writing some data in an auxiliary file be optimal ? Maybe there would be a way to use the hash of the last commit ? That would probably lead to rather random and annoying label names though.

[image]

Comment: unrelated but you are  missing a `%` after `#1` (otherwise you get at least a word space and possibly a line break between the text and the node holding the marginpar)

Answer (score 1):

This is really no different to `\section{hello}`  or any other automatically numbered thing.

The standard latex way would be to use `\note{\label{abc}some text here}`  then you have the internal stable identifier label `abc` which you can refer to in discussion (or in the  document as `\ref{abc}`) even if the text or number of the note changes.

Comment: Well I suppose I wanted to make it simpler for my collaborators, so that they did not to have to add a label by hand every time, but maybe that's definitely the only rather simple way to go.